# Bad to have a constructor output data, like writing to a spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, class, google-apps-script, constructor

Working in Google Apps Script. Have a class that stores data from a file as well as metadata *about* the file that's read from a record on a spreadsheet. The constructor reads from both the data and the spreadsheet record.

Sometimes, however, the file has changed since the spreadsheet record was written. This easy enough to detect and synchronize...but is that okay to do from within the constructor?

I could also just have the constructor detect this out-of-synch condition and make that info available as a field. A separate synchronize() function could do the job of writing the updated data to the spreadsheet record.

Any opinions/rules on this? Is it bad to have the constructor doing that much?

Comment: What is a "spreadsheet record" and why would it be different from the underlying file?

Comment: Yes, in general you should avoid side effects in constructors. If necessary, use a static method that does the synchronisation and then returns a new instance.

Comment: @Bergi A row of cells in a different spreadsheet with file data and contents, as well as some metadata. For instance file.title, file.id, the values in a range in a sheet in the find, and the ids of some other files it's associated with. It could be different than the file it's a record of if the user had opened that file and edited it.

Comment: @Bergi The method wouldn't even have to return a new instance. It would just be writing data to the spreadsheet record to match the current contents of the file. Why is it important that it be static?

Comment: Yes, you can make it a normal method as well, it just sounded as if you wanted/needed to do it upon creation of an instance. It just should not be part of the constructor, it should be possible to construct an instance without having the effect run.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, do you mean a method that calls the constructor, then does the synchronization and returns an instance? Maybe I'm not sure what is meant by static method.

Comment: …or the other way round, a static method (`MyClass.createSynced(record)`) that does the synchronisation and *then* calls the constructor to return an instance containing the fresh data.